# SELECT COUNT for specific values in certain column

Tags: mysql, select, count

I'd like to know how can I count specific rows with a condition. It's probably a simple count but I got burned badly on this today.
I'm not really sure if I'm explaining myself well, so here's a picture:

[image: SQL Tryit]

(for the record it's from the online SQL editor; here's a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in). Just make sure you restore database on the right and click on Customers).

I need to count the number of customers for each country. Since the Country column has 21 distinct values, I need to have a table with 2 columns named Countries and Count and 21 rows with the counts themselves. How can I do that?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Good tip, but... what am I exactly counting here actually? What is in the brackets behind "COUNT"? It pains me to ask like this since I do joins regularly but this just caught me completely dumb.

Comment: You can count the number of rows using `COUNT(*)` or any specific column using `COUNT(<COLUMN_NAME>)`.

Comment: I got it. Shame on me. Still, thanks for the responses.